# Preg match filenames from html content

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

This expression find filenames in html content which contains digits, letters and underscores.

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+\.\w{2,4})/', $content);
```

But do not find filename like file-name.txt. How can I change expression to find filenames with dash and other legal characters?

Comment: Define *other legal characters*.

Comment: Minimally it is dash, isn't it? In filename could be space, but it would can generate strange results (for example aaa .bbb could be filename or text presentation). So dash is legal character which I would like add to expression. I tried it, but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, the file suffix does not contain non-letters/digits: Doesn't a char class like `[\w-]` do the trick for you? What exactly did you try?

`preg_match_all('/([\w-]+\.\w{2,4})/', $content);` works for me for filenames like file-name.txt

Beware: the hyphen has to be at the end, otherwise a range is assumed for the char class by PHP.